# Using pfSense firewall aliases with BIND package

Tags: bind, pfsense

I´m a pfSense newbie and got the last version of pfSense running fine. The network hosts a few web sites (all with the same IP address) I´m trying to use the firewall aliases with BIND. I created a firewall alias named "publicIP" and it´s desirable to input such alias in the "Base Domain IP" and "IP address" fields in the BIND package, so when the public IP changes we won´t have to edit every record in the zones (there are about twenty all pointing to the same IP)
Can this be accomplished?

Comment: I *think* you're asking about what in DNS jargon are called [`CNAME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) records, but which has nothing to do with pfSense...

Comment: I´m aware what `CNAME` are. What we're looking for is BIND to respond for `A` records with the IP indicated in a firewall alias so if the IP changes, the alias is modified and not the `A` record itself

Comment: @alvaroc I'm trying to accomplish the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Still don't . I regard this a basic function that should be present.